# multi-touch support with fujitsu t900

Tags: drivers, tablet, multi-touch

The pen works great out of the box. Any idea how to get multi-touch working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Please see this to get help with MultiTouch in Ubuntu:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch#Community%20Help

Make sure you include the result of lsusb when you ask your question there. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Multitouch is supposed to be better supported in Maverick...
http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/455

Maybe you just have to wait, or if you can't, install the Beta :-)

Comment: installed the beta. still not working. hmmm.

Comment: :-( Well, I'm sorry, that was just a hint.